# Recommended way to modify assembler instructions in IDA

Tags: ida, assembly

What is the easiest way (or is there any) to modify an instruction
inside a binary opened inside IDA and save the changes to the original? 
Is there a builtin assembler who's output I can place at a certain offset? How can I save back a binary after having edited the hex view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite easy with IDA Pro:

With the cursor at the first instruction you want to modify go to Edit | Patch Program | Assemble

[image: IDA Pro | Edit | Patch Program | Assemble]

Change the instruction(s) as required until you are done, then press OK
[image: IDA Pro | Assemble Instruction]

Finally choose Edit | Patch Program | Apply patches to input file (and optionally make a backup).

Here is an example: https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2013/05/23/application-compatibility-fixing-to-the-extreme/

From the Help:

> Edit|Patch core submenu   This submenu allows you to patch the image
>   of the input file. More precisely, IDA never modifies the input file.
>   The image of the input file which was loaded to the database will be
>   modified.  You can modify the image of the input file:
>
> ```
>     - change a byte
>     - change a word
>     - enter an assembler instruction (only for IBM PC)
> ```
>
> IDA will display the original value, the current value and file
>   offset. If the file offset is equal to 0xFFFFFFFF then the current
>   byte comes from a compressed page (LX/LE/NE iterated pages, for
>   example) and/or it is not possible to tell the file position.  You can
>   create a difference file and use an external tool to apply the patches
>   or you can apply the patches directly to the file using IDA.
>
> The following commands are availabe:
>
> Patch byte or word  Assemble...  Apply patches to input file...
>
> See also:   Produce EXE file  Produce DIF file  Edit submenu.